# How to extract the claims from JWT token

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

I'm using the dgrijalva/jwt-go/ package.

I would like to extract the payload from the token, and I couldn't find a way to do it.

---

Example (taken from : https://jwt.io/):

for encoded:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ

I would like to extract the payload:

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true
}
```

---

I will be grateful for an example (using golang).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sample Code:

```
    func extractClaims(tokenStr string) (jwt.MapClaims, bool) {
        hmacSecretString := // Value
        hmacSecret := []byte(hmacSecretString)
        token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenStr, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
             // check token signing method etc
             return hmacSecret, nil
        })

        if err != nil {
            return nil, false
        }

        if claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok && token.Valid {
            return claims, true
        } else {
            log.Printf("Invalid JWT Token")
            return nil, false
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to extract if token from another microservices, i dont had secret

Comment: Ideally you will need the secret to decrypt tokens in case of JWE( encrypted tokens). If you are using JWS (signed tokens) you can still read the payload, but not verify the signature.

Comment: If you wish to get claims without validating signature, just pass `nil` instead of function to `jwt.Parse`

Comment: Passing `nil` does not work, as it will fail with error: "no Keyfunc was provided". https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/issues/37

Comment: Then you split it `parts = strings.Split(tokenString, ".")` and decode second part `base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(parts[1])`. It's easy to check jwt tokens at jwt.io

Comment: Or pass keyfunc, and just `return nil, nil` inside of it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to extract the claims without secret, you can use the `ParseUnverified`

```
func extractUnverifiedClaims(tokenString string) (string, error) {
    var name string
    token, _, err := new(jwt.Parser).ParseUnverified(tokenString, jwt.MapClaims{})
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    if claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok {
        name = fmt.Sprint(claims["name"])
    }

    if name == "" {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("invalid token payload")
    }
    return name, nil
}
```

Full code: https://go.dev/play/p/a7CdBNL8LzW