# Getting nil instead of *jwt.Token when requesting token

Tags: go, jwt

I'm trying to a the token to verify the user role but I get an error:

> interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not *jwt.Token

I did something similar requesting the user ID and it worked but here I can't seem to get the token.

Code:

```
func AdminRoutes(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        u := c.Get("user").(*jwt.Token)
        claims := u.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
        for _, item := range routes[claims["role"].(string)] {
            if c.Request().RequestURI == item && claims["role"] != "admin" {
                return c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, "Role not suitable for function.")
            }
        }
        return next(c)
    }
}
```

I've tried to `c.Set()` the token but `c.Get()` doesn't work after.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859244/golang-extract-the-claims-from-jwt-token/39859575#39859575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `c.Get("user")` returns `nil` value, and what you did was performing type assertion on `nil` value, it's the reason why the error occurs.

I suggest to put some checking on `c.Get()` before asserting it.

```golang
if temp := c.Get("user"); temp != nil {
    u := temp.(*jwt.Token)
    claims := u.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    for _, item := range routes[claims["role"].(string)] {
        if c.Request().RequestURI == item && claims["role"] != "admin" {
            return c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, "Role not suitable for function.")
        }
    }
}
```